# Auto fill registration form fields

Tags: java, jsp, spring-data-jpa

I have a jsp page for registration form where there are 2 fields regDate and endDate. RegDate is today’s date and endDate is one year after today. Now I want to auto fill these fields in my jsp to store them In MySQL database. I’m using annotation based spring mvc and hibernate jpa annotations spring data etc

Comment: What is the specific problem you're facing? Could you please share the code that you've tried so far?

Comment: Those values can be passed from the controller to the view (JSP page) as model parameters. Please review the Spring MVC documentation for details on passing model parameters from controllers to views.

Answer (score 0):

For an HTML text field, you can to supply a string representation of a date to the element’s `value` attribute. To get the current date, call `java.util.Calendar.getInstance()` and use the resulting `Calendar`’s `getTime()` method, which returns a `java.util.Date` object, to determine regDate. Increase the `Calendar`’s year with `add(Calendar.YEAR, 1)` and get another `Date` for next year’s date.

**Edit:** I had broken code before, but this should work.

```
<%@ page import = "java.util.Calendar" %>
<%@ page import = "java.util.Date" %>
<%! public Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); %>
```

And later in the page:

```
<input type="text" name="regDate" value=<%= "\""+cal.getTime()+"\"" %> />
<% cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1); %>
<input type="text" name="endDate" value=<%= "\""+cal.getTime()+"\"" %> />
```

Comment: Now i am getting error as "Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'endDate'"

Comment: I actually did a bunch of dumb things in my answer; I’ll edit it once I have code that runs.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include code that works based on my interpretation of your question. If you think I interpreted it wrong or it still doesn’t work for you, please explain a bit more about your problem.